# Context initialization failing in Liferay 5.2 with Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, liferay

When I deploy my portlet in liferay 5.2 with Tomcat 7, A certain bean fail to get initialised.
I am using service builder to genreate these.
I have checked in portlet-spring.xml and there is entry for the bean.
And also the particular bean does exist.

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tbb.ump.admin.service.FoodLocalService.impl': Injection of BeanReference fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.tbb.ump.admin.service.MeasureUnitLocalService.impl' is defined
at com.liferay.portal.spring.annotation.BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(BeanReferenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Not able to find out the issue, I have recently migrated to Tomcat 7.
Environment :
Tomcat 7.0.22
Liferay 5.2.3
Service builder 5.2
Servlet-APi-3
Spring 3

Answer (score 0):

You probably have 
given class name instead of bean name

> No bean named 'com.tbb.ump.admin.service.MeasureUnitLocalService.impl' is defined

Comment: can you post a bit of spring xml file

Comment: <bean id="com.tbb.ump.admin.service.MeasureUnitLocalService.impl" class="com.tbb.ump.admin.service.impl.MeasureUnitLocalServiceImpl" />
*****FYI..This code is generated by service builder

Comment: and from where it is being referenced ? is this from the same spring xml file ?

Comment: From baseImpl of food      @BeanReference(name = "com.tbb.ump.admin.service.MeasureUnitLocalService.impl")
 protected MeasureUnitLocalService measureUnitLocalService;